# Openlayers 5 click vector feature style circle popup [SOLUTION!]

Tags: openlayers

there is already a working script for OL 3.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DXnDfStbvbetOtdU

Is there anyone who can rewrite that in OL 5?

Please as in the example for OL 3 without Ajax, JQuery and NodeJS. Please include with:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css
https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js

Comment: The links provided were sufficient to demonstrate the problem.  Substituting the latest ol js and css urls in the working script produces a run time error when referencing the deprecated ol.animation

Comment: "deprecated". OK. I have seen in the console a problem with the ".ani" and have hide him. Than was a problem with "getTarget()" and i'm confused.

Comment: It's better to use getTargetElement() as it always returns a div element, getTarget() can return a div id or element, but when as in the example the element is specified in the map constructor either method will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it won't work in OpenLayers 4 or 5 because the the way animations work has changed since OL3.

In `ol-popup.js` you would need to remove

```
this.ani = options.ani;
if (this.ani === undefined) {
    this.ani = ol.animation.pan;
}
```

and change

```
if (this.ani && this.ani_opts) {
    this.ani_opts.source = center;
    this.getMap().beforeRender(this.ani(this.ani_opts));
}
this.getMap().getView().setCenter(this.getMap().getCoordinateFromPixel(px));

return this.getMap().getView().getCenter();
```

to

```
center = this.getMap().getCoordinateFromPixel(px);
if (this.ani_opts) {
    this.ani_opts.center = center;
    this.getMap().getView().animate(this.ani_opts);
} else {
    this.getMap().getView().setCenter(center);
}

return center;
```

Comment: you are realy helpfull! I have a problem, you have a solution. I'm ignore the VOTEWAR! Many thanks @Mike!!!